# Crysis 2 doesn't match my gamepad inputs

Tags: steam, controllers, crysis-2

I'm using a Speedlink XEOX Pro Analog Wireless Gamepad.

When playing Crysis 2 Maximum Edition on Steam, my controller input doesn't register until I push quite far on the right analog stick; this makes aiming difficult and ruins the experience.

I checked the Windows game pad options, and it's receiving input with less movement.

How can I change the Crysis 2 settings to match my game pad inputs?

Notes:
I've already changed the in game sensitivity settings. The controller is setup to Xinput